# MS Access - randomly select records based on percentage

Tags: ms-access

I have a database in which I need to randomly select records per date, per user, and each user has a different percentage of records which have to be selected.

If I only have one date and one user, I can do this like:

```
    strSQL = "SELECT TOP " & intPercent & " PERCENT * FROM [tblRevision] WHERE & _ 
DateCreated = #" & dteDate & "# ORDER BY RandomNumber DESC;"
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction so I can apply this to a recordset containing more that one date and more than one user.

I was suggested that my question is a possible duplicate of this posting: [Random sorting query Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454825/random-sorting-query-access), but it does not solve my question of more that one date and more than one user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random sorting query Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454825/random-sorting-query-access)

Answer (score 0):

How about a UNION statement?

```
select first set of data
UNION
select second set of data
UNION
select third set of data
ORDER BY col1, col2
```

Comment: How is that applicable to the question?

Comment: To use three dates, make three select statements and UNION them together:

strSQL = "SELECT TOP " & intPercent & " PERCENT * FROM [tblRevision] WHERE & DateCreated = #" & dteDate & "# " & 
"UNION SELECT TOP " & intPercent & " PERCENT * FROM [tblRevision] WHERE & DateCreated = #" & dteDate2 & "# " & 
"UNION SELECT TOP " & intPercent & " PERCENT * FROM [tblRevision] WHERE & DateCreated = #" & dteDate3 & "# " & 
"ORDER BY RandomNumber DESC;"

Comment: I may not be understanding this, but it seems to me that this makes it very static. What if there are more or less than 3 dates to do this on. Will I have to modify the query every time?

Comment: You could use a series of IF statements to build the SQL string. 
E.g., create the first statement. 
IF there's a Date2 then strSQL = strSQL & " UNION " & strSQL2, etc.